# Deshabilitar boton derecho del mouse dentro de un iframe, embed o object, el cual contiene un pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola que tal espero que todo bien, mi consulta es la siguiente tengo un pdf incrustado en un embed por mas que quiero bloquear el boton derecho del mouse, en el objeto no lo acepta lo acepta en toda la pagian web menos en el objeto, ya sea iframe, embed o object por favor si alguien sabe algo o de paginas que pueda consultar ya voy 2 dias buscando toda la informacion posible pero no funciona al momento de ejecutarlo cuando hago clic derecho en el pdf que esta incrustado en dicho objeto.

este es mi codigo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        var msg = "¡El botón derecho está desactivado para este sitio !";
        function disableIE() {
            if (document.all) { alert(msg); return false; }
        }
        function disableNS(e) {
            if (document.layers || (document.getElementById && !document.all)) {
                if (e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) { alert(msg); return false; }
            }
        }
        if (document.layers) {
            document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN); document.onmousedown = disableNS;
        } else {
            document.onmouseup = disableNS; document.oncontextmenu = disableIE;
        }
        document.oncontextmenu = new Function("alert(msg);return false")
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="pdf">
        <embed src="~/Recursos/Documento/@Model.DocLibro#toolbar=0" style="width:100%; height:620px;"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

GRacias de antemano
Saludos
Andres

Comment: Siento decirlo asi amigo... pero si la idea de tu iframe o tu object o cualquier cosa que sea un frame es para que sea mas dificil que el usuario pueda ver rutas o usar el archivo o acceder al recurso, no es tan sencillo como simplemente bloquear el click derecho en el, hay muchisimas pero muchisimas cosas que no estas teniendo en cuenta si lo que deseas es prevenir que el usuario pueda ver tu recurso, descargarlo o incluso acceder a el directamente.

Comment: Sin embargo no todo es triste en esta vida, existe aún una opción mas abajo te mostrare un link de una pregunta que se hizo relacionada a como proteger recursos que yo respondí hace un tiempo, en caso de serte de utilidad podemos dar por concluida la pregunta, puesto que esa pregunta justamente ayuda a proteger los recursos del lado del cliente, haciendo que sean inaccesibles para el usuario aunque habra la consola del navegador.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo bloquear la combinación de teclas Ctrl+U y Ctrl+S?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/327080/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-bloquear-la-combinaci%c3%b3n-de-teclas-ctrlu-y-ctrls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        var msg = "¡El botón derecho está desactivado para este sitio !";
        function disableIE() {
            if (document.all) { alert(msg); return false; }
        }
        function disableNS(e) {
            if (document.layers || (document.getElementById && !document.all)) {
                if (e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) { alert(msg); return false; }
            }
        }
        if (document.layers) {
            document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN); document.onmousedown = disableNS;
        } else {
            document.onmouseup = disableNS; document.oncontextmenu = disableIE;
        }
        document.oncontextmenu = ev =>{
          ev.preventDefault();
          console.log("Prevented to open menu!");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="pdf">
        <embed src="http://www.colvema.org/pdf/consejos/origenperrogato.pdf#toolbar=0" style="width:100%; height:620px;"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

En caso de que el problema no sea de seguridad, si no que mas bien simplemente quieres evitar que el usuario pueda abrir el menu contextual sin tener en cuenta que hay muchas otras maneras de que el usuario pueda acceder a ese recurso, entonces esto te funcionara:

```
document.oncontextmenu = ev =>{
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log("Prevented to open menu!");
}
```

Es una modificación del código que ya tenias, todo el resto de tu código sigue igual.

Donde `ev.preventDefault` le indica al evento que cancele cualquier comportamiento asociado con la acción que se ha realizado y con el evento, por lo cual una de las acciones asociadas al `click` derecho es abrir el menu contextual, el cual será bloqueado por `ev.preventDefault`.

De hecho no se a que se debe que últimamente  al crear una función, los usuarios escriben `Function` en vez de `function`, no se si es un error o existe la clase function y hay una cierta diferencia entre `Function` y `function`, me gustaría aclarar esta duda, pero hasta donde se no es valido `Function` si no `function`.

Comment: Hola, si entiendo y tambien he probado dicha sentencia, pero igual me permite al momento de cargar mi pdf en el iframe me muestra el menu contextual, mas que todo de momento se quiere solo eso, pero si bien me aparece el mensaje en el log que asumo si esta entrando a la funcion, el iframe no lo toma en cuenta.

Comment: Ah si, lo siento, se me habia olvidado, talvez deba editar la respuesta, recuerda que un iframe es como si tuvieras una pagina dentro de otra pagina, por lo cual hay dos DOM, por este motivo es necesario especificar como elemento el iframe y no el document, asi que seria buena idea que intentaras esto mismo pero usando la referencia del iframe y no el document,  en tu caso es un embed.