# Evitar ver código JS en navegadores

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Tengo este código en AJAX en mi archivo JS. Al inspeccionar el código, noto que puedo ver el código JS.

Donde paso los parámetros del controlador de PHP quería evitar eso. Existe algún método posible, gracias por su ayuda, espero su respuesta[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese código que debe de existir en el lado del cliente (hablando del navegador), no puede ser ocultado de ninguna forma. La única opción es quitarlo y tratar de implementarlo en el lado del servidor, para el caso de tu js). Para el contenido HTML, solo es contenido textual y siempre podrá ser inspeccionado, sin importar reglas CSS u otras alternativas. Imagina un documento, no hay forma de ocultar nada del texto que le pertence al cliente, podrás cambiarle sus atributos pero siempre estará ahí, inspeccionable siempre

Comment: Busca información sobre ofuscar el código.

Comment: Pues... de hecho si hay una forma, pero esta forma solo es aplicable a `javascript`, no te servira para ocultar `HTML` ni para ocultar cualquier otro tipo de documento, tengo una respuesta al respecto para poder ocultar `javascript` desde el lado del cliente, pero pues ya hay una respuesta tambien valida al respecto, de igual forma te comparto la mia:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/327080/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-bloquear-la-combinaci%c3%b3n-de-teclas-ctrlu-y-ctrls

Comment: En ese enlace que he compartido si lo miras puede que el titulo no tenga nada que ver con tu pregunta, pero enrealidad cuando miras bien lo que el usuario pregunta te das cuenta de que lo que quiere hacer es exactamente lo que tu estas intentando (ocultar codigo), por ende creo que te puede servir hasta cierto punto si se trata de `javascript`.